# Why can't I access WSL directories from my windows terminal?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, directory-structure

I have made a python script in WSL using VSCode. I want to call this script from another python script that is running in Windows.

My plan was to use `os.system()` to command line into wsl and start the script from it's directory, however when I go into windows terminal to try to start it manually, I can't access any of my directories.

The path I am attempting to access from terminal is \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\ben\apps and root user can't access it either.

Windows terminal:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\benja> wsl
ben@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/Users/benja$ cd ~
ben@DESKTOP:~$ ls
ben@DESKTOP:~$ ls -a
.  ..  .bash_history  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .profile
ben@DESKTOP:~$ cd ..
ben@DESKTOP:/home$ ls
ben
ben@DESKTOP:/home$ cd /ben
-bash: cd: /ben: No such file or directory
ben@DESKTOP:/home$ cd ..
ben@DESKTOP:/$ ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  init  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
ben@DESKTOP:/$ cd ..
ben@DESKTOP:/$ cd /home/ben/apps
```

Comment: As @YoraiLevi mentioned in an answer, your `cd /ben` fails because it should be `cd ~/ben`.  However, you don't seen to have the `apps` directory that you think you do.  Can you go back into VSCode and recheck the directory you think you saved your script to?  Also note that you should typically edit WSL files in VSCode by starting in WSL, then executing something like `code .`.  Make sure you have the "Remote - WSL" extension installed.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing `/ben` aka root_directory/ben
try: `~/apps` or `cd ben`

Comment: Agreed on the first part, but note that the `ls` in the home directory didn't show an `~/apps` directory (`ls` returned no results other than hidden files via `ls -la`), so that's not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

WSL has both Ubuntu and Debian. `apps` is in Ubuntu, however my WSL was defaulting to Debian. That is why the directories were empty.